# error due to mentioning package name

Tags: java

```
package carwash;
public class CarWash
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("car wash is now open");
    }

}
```

compiled above using Javac successfully, but got an error

*could not find or load main class*
during the run time.
I tried without the package name.

```
    public class CarWash
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("car wash is now open");
    }

}
```

It worked without any errors.
What is the reason for this ? "thank you!".

Comment: You're  missing the most important bit, what directory you tried to run it in, and your command statements where you show us how you tried to run it.

Comment: Are you running it from the parent directory to `carwash`?  Are you using `java carwash.CarWash`?  Is the `.java` file stored in the subdirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is file directory your working with, given below is what will work. 
Assuming your working folder is:

```
D:\
  |
  `---Jack(working folder)
       |
       `---carwash(package)
             |
             `---CarWash.java
```

In cmd/terminal, your path must be:

```
D:\Jack\>
```

Compile command:

```
D:\Jack\>javac carwash\CarWash.java
```

Run command:

```
D:\Jack\>java carwash.CarWash
```

P.S. for windows

Answer (score 0):

When running code in a package (which you should) you include the package name when you run it on Windows (something like)

```
java -cp ".;%CLASSPATH%" carwash.CarWash
```

or on *nix systems

```
java -cp ".:$CLASSPATH" carwash.CarWash
```

note that the packages are mapped to directories on the disk so `CarWash.class` should be in a `carwash` subdirectory.